# VR hand tracking in unity with custom models

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I am developing a VR game where you can choose between multiple characters and thus need various different models for hands.
Target platforms are the Meta Quest 2 as well as PCVR and I want to support the Quests hand tracking functionality.

Here is what I want, further down is what i did so far:
Ideally I can imagine it to look like this:

- There is an armature with a specific set of bones, eg `palm`, `thumbLower`, `thumbUpper`,  `indexLower`, `indexMiddle`, `indexUpper`, etc
- There are a few animations for that armature, like `relaxed`, `fist`, `indexFingerPointing`
- I have a script that is aware of the set of bones and the existing animations and can take in whatever model as long as it has an armature with the exact same naming.
  The script could then check for Quest 2 Hand Tracking and if enabled move the joints directly according to the tracking input, otherwise use any controllers grip and trigger to transition between `relaxed` (no trigger, no grip), `indexFingerPointing` (no trigger, but grip pressed) and `fist` (trigger and grip pressed)

Here is what I did:
Searching Unitys packages I found the `XR Interaction Toolkit` as well as `XR Hands` which I am using in versions 2.3.0 and 1.1.0 respectively.
The `XR Hands` come with a HandVisualizer which is a great starting point but I am having trouble using hand models other than the ones that come with the package. Those were the steps:

1. bought a collection of hand models on the unity assetstore
2. imported the `RightHand.fbx` that comes with the `XR Hands` package in blender (it comes with an armature which I guess has a specific naming scheme, which is why I wanted to copy that)
3. also imported one of the models from the collection, say `GlovesHandRight`
4. deleted `GlovesHandRight` armature but kept the mesh and deleted the `RightHands` mesh but kept the armature
5. moved all the bones of the former `RightHands` armature to match the `GlovesHandRight`
6. in object mode, selected the `GlovesHandRight`, then the armature and selected "with automatic weights"

In pose mode I can see the mesh deforming when I move the bones.
And in object mode the scene hierarchy looks exactly like it does in the original `RightHand.fbx` file

After exporting the file to FBX and using it with the `HandVisualizer` script instead of the original `RightHand.fbx` I get the error message:

```
Hand transform hierarchy not set correctly - couldn't find Wrist joint!
Hand transform hierarchy not set correctly - couldn't find ThumbMetacarpal joint!
Hand transform hierarchy not set correctly - couldn't find IndexMetacarpal joint!
Hand transform hierarchy not set correctly - couldn't find MiddleMetacarpal joint!
Hand transform hierarchy not set correctly - couldn't find RingMetacarpal joint!
Hand transform hierarchy not set correctly - couldn't find LittleMetacarpal joint!
all at
UnityEngine.XR.Hands.Samples.VisualizerSample.HandVisualizer:Update () (at Assets/Samples/XR Hands/1.1.0/HandVisualizer/Scripts/HandVisualizer.cs:144)
```

Since I am a noob in blender (which is why the above took me like 3 hours) any input regarding what could cause the problem is very much appreciated as well as any input how to approach this problem differently, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem was simply that blender adds an extra root bone when exporting to FBX, so I tried out that custom fbx exporter https://github.com/A-Ribeiro/CustomBlenderFBXExporter and I can now see the custom hands working with Quest 2 hand tracking, so I guess I consider it solved